# The import org.springframework.web cannot be resolved. Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle

The import org.springframework.web cannot be resolved.

Eclipse cannot import Spring libraries.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import task1.exception.NotFoundException;
```

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.3.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}



apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'task1'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

[image]

But when i build this project in terminal it already builds and run.

Comment: Have you tried `Project -> Clean` options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-click the `build.gradle` file and do:

```
file -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies
```